# Is there a distinction between NEOs and near-Earth asteroids? Is there a difference?

Tags: terminology, near-earth-object

My "real question" is in Space Exploration Meta ([neo (near-earth-object) and near-earth-asteroid tags, do we need both?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1459/12102)), but I think that astronomers will be able to help understand the situation and terminology.

**Question:** Is there a distinction between NEOs and near-Earth asteroids? Is there a difference? Or is it a distinction without a difference?

I noticed for example that here in Astronomy SE there is just [near-earth-object](/questions/tagged/near-earth-object).

Comment: This University of Iowa Department of Physics and Astronomy site seems to indicate all near earth asteroids are NEOs: http://astro.physics.uiowa.edu/ITU/labs/professional-labs/introduction-to-impact/. Does that sufficiently address your question?

Comment: A more clear-cut example: http://icarus.astro.umd.edu/features/whatrneos.shtml

Comment: @called2voyage yes it does, very nicely thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Near Earth Objects (NEOs) include asteroids (Near Earth Asteroids (NEAs)) and a few percent of comets (Near Earth Comets (NECs)). As shown by the [Update to Determine the Feasibility of Enhancing the Search and Characterization of NEOs (NEO SDT Report)](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/2017_neo_sdt_final_e-version.pdf) in Section 2.3, the risk from Near Earth Comets is about 1% that of asteroids. So "NEO" tends to be assumed to mean "asteroid" unless otherwise stated.